# Update customer custom attribute in magento2 programatically

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I need to update custom attribute based on response from external API ,How to update the custom attribute from controller , here is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace test\Org\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

     /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $curl;
    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Curl $curl,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        )
    {
        $this->curl = $curl;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

   

    public function execute()
    {
        $numone = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numone');
        $numtwo = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numtwo');
     $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
         $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

          
        
                $URL = 'api';
               
               
                //set curl options
               // $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                //set curl header
                $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //get request with url
                $this->curl->get($URL);
          
                $response = $this->curl->getBody();
 **//need to add a code for updating a custom attribute that is getting from response**

                $resp= json_decode($response, TRUE);
                $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('test\Org\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('test_Org::test.phtml')
                ->setData('numone',$resp['nmk'])
                ->toHtml();

                 $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
               // return $response;
      //  $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
       return $result;
    }
    
   
}
```

I need to save the response to a custom attribute named external_id in the customer entity

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are getting back in curl response to match customer in Magento, I had given both Id & Email option here in code, please try below code, hope it will help:

```
<?php

namespace test\Org\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

     /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $curl;
    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Curl $curl,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        )
    {
        $this->curl = $curl;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

   

    public function execute()
    {
        $numone = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numone');
        $numtwo = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numtwo');
     $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
         $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

          
        
                $URL = 'api';
               
               
                //set curl options
               // $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                //set curl header
                $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //get request with url
                $this->curl->get($URL);
          
                $response = $this->curl->getBody();
 **//need to add a code for updating a custom attribute that is getting from response**

                $customerid = $response->customerid;
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                /* Or */
                $customeremail = $response->customeremail;
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($customeremail);
               /* code to update data using Cutomer object */
                $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
                $customerData->setId($customer->getId());
                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('external_id', $responsevalue);
                $customer->updateData($customerData);
                $customer->save();
                

                $resp= json_decode($response, TRUE);
                $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('test\Org\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('test_Org::test.phtml')
                ->setData('numone',$resp['nmk'])
                ->toHtml();

                 $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
               // return $response;
      //  $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
       return $result;
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::getByEmail() in /Controller/Result/Result1.php:72

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getDataModel()

Comment: have modified the code, please try this one and also if you already have customer Id you can remove the 2 lines which are written for fetching customer object using email address. 

$customeremail = $response->customeremail;
$customer = $this->customerRepository->get($customeremail);

Comment: did you try that ? if worked please accept the answer so it can help the community